# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'

Tags: python, algorithm

```py
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0, next_ele=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next_ele = next_ele


class Solution(object):
    def is_palindrome(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        q: list = []

        if not head:
            return True

        node = head
        while node is not None:
            q.append(node.val)
            node = node.next_ele

        while len(q) > 1:
            if q.pop(0) != q.pop():
                return False
        return True


input_list = [1, 2, 2, 1]
s = Solution()
s.is_palindrome(input_list)
```

**Console:**
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'

**My problem**
This is my solution of "Palindrome Linked List" in Leetcode.
This runs perfect on Leetcode repl but I am trying to run it on Pycharm.
and I got AttributeError like that.

**What I tried:**
I thought "head" which stated in the form of the list didn't fit the class which I defined on the top (ListNode).
so I tried these

1. s.is_palindrome(ListNode(input_list))
   so that the input(head: ListNode) can be fit in the definition, is_palindrome with the type of "ListNode".
   but I got this with **input_list[1, 2]** => True
   which is wrong answer.
2. node = ListNode(head)
   Just tried if this works but also got the wrong answer.

Can anyone please help me with the right solution?

Comment: You need to create a linked list with `ListNode`s and send the first node in this list to `is_palindrome`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an array to your function which expects a Linked List node. Convert your array to a linked list using something like this:

```py
input_list = [1, 2, 2, 1]
nodes = [ListNode(val = i) for i in input_list]
for i in range(len(nodes)-1):
    nodes[i].next_ele = nodes[i+1]
s = Solution()
s.is_palindrome(nodes[0])
```